# Facebook Connect for iPhone - Request to like a page

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm not sure if this is possible but using Facebook Connect for iPhone, can you request to like a facebook page? If this means showing the FB dialog box that is fine!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't resolved this one, here is a neat tutorial:
http://petersteinberger.com/2010/06/add-facebook-like-button-with-facebook-connect-iphone-sdk/